# json data read object with true and false condition

Tags: javascript, php, json

i used a local storage json file to save my form data. but i want to make delete functions for some purpose. i used a button to update my json object using a id number.
this is my json code for storing data.

```
{
  "id":"6",
  "firstname":"dmk",
  "lastname":"stc",
  "age":"32",
  "is_active":"true"
}
```

i want to make is_active to false when delete button clicks in my form. how to get a model or alert and delete it.

```
<a type='submit' 
   class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' 
   role='button' id='btnDelete' 
   style='margin-left: 10px;'>
  Delete
</a>
```

this is my javascript code to retrive data using json file

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var ajaxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "form.json";

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var details = '';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

        var people = response.people;

        var output = '';

        output += "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
        output += "<tr><th scope='col'>id</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

        for(x in response){

            output += "<tr><td>" + response[x].id + "</td><td>" + response[x].firstname + "</td><td>"+response[x].lastname+"</td><td>"+response[x].age+"</td><td><a href='edit.php?id="+response[x].id+"&firstname="+response[x].firstname+"&lastname="+response[x].lastname+"&age="+response[x].age+"' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm active' role='button' aria-pressed='true'>Edit</a><a href='index.php?id="+response[x].id+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' role='button' id='btnDelete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'    style='margin-left: 10px;'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

        }


        output += "</table> ";



       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: what is your localStorage key ?? do you want to make an update and save it to the localStorage again ??

Comment: i'm not using localstorage key. i only use json file to store. i wrote a php code to insert data into a json array

Comment: show your php code to generate that json file.

Comment: i edit my question and added php code to retrive data using json file

Comment: that's javascript code

Comment: oh sorry not php using javascript